# resharper changing base to this

Tags: refactoring, resharper, this, radix

I have this simple program to show the issue.

```
using System;

namespace Bug
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var x = new MyDerivedClass();
         x.DoSomething("data");
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }

   public class MyBaseClass
   {
      protected void DoSomething(object data)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("calling MyBaseClass::DoSomething()");
      }
   }

   public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
   {
      public void DoSomething(string data)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("calling MyDerivedClass::DoSomething()");
         base.DoSomething(data);
      }
   }
}
```

When I do Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C and clean-up with Resharper,
it changes

```
base.DoSomething(data);
```

to

```
this.DoSomething(data);
```

and indicates a recursive call.
Running this will create Stack Overflow :-)

To "fix" this, you have to write

```
base.DoSomething((object)data);
```

and this will be changed to

```
this.DoSomething((object) data);
```

which is now correct.

Is this really only Resharper's bug or my wrong design (naming)?

Comment: Resharper 8.2.0.2160

Comment: I've tested this with ReSharper 9.1 and it does *not* remove the base qualifier... It calls the base method with `object` argument as expected.